# Read py.test's output as object

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, python-unittest

Earlier I was using python `unittest` in my project, and with it came `unittest.TextTestRunner` and `unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase`. I used them for the following reasons,

1. Control the execution of unittest using a wrapper function which calls the unittests's run method. I did not want the command line approach.
2. Read the unittest's output from the result object and upload the results to a bug tracking system which allow us to generate some complex reports on code stability.

Recently there was a decision made to switch to `py.test`, how can I do the above using py.test ? I don't want to parse any CLI/HTML to get the output from py.test. I also don't want to write too much code on my unit test file to do this.

Can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the pytest's hook to intercept the test result reporting:

`conftest.py`:

```
import pytest

@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_logreport(report):
    yield

    # Define when you want to report:
    # when=setup/call/teardown,
    # fields: .failed/.passed/.skipped
    if report.when == 'call' and report.failed:

        # Add to the database or an issue tracker or wherever you want.
        print(report.longreprtext)
        print(report.sections)
        print(report.capstdout)
        print(report.capstderr)
```

Similarly, you can intercept one of these hooks to inject your code at the needed stage (in some cases, with the try-except around `yield`):

- `pytest_runtest_protocol(item, nextitem)`
- `pytest_runtest_setup(item)`
- `pytest_runtest_call(item)`
- `pytest_runtest_teardown(item, nextitem)`
- `pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call)`
- `pytest_runtest_logreport(report)`

Read more: [Writing pytest  plugins](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html)

All of this can be easily done either with a tiny plugin made as a simple installable library, or as a pseudo-plugin `conftest.py` which just lies around in one of the directories with the tests.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like pytest lets you [launch from Python code](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#calling-pytest-from-python-code) instead of using the command line. It looks like you just pass the same arguments to the function call that would be on the command line.

Pytest will create [resultlog format files](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#creating-resultlog-format-files), but the feature is deprecated. The documentation suggests using the [pytest-tap plugin](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest-tap) that produces files in the Test Anything Protocol.